# Changing Scanner type to arrays of number

Tags: java

I have the following codes and instead of typing the numbers using scanner function.  I want to use an array instead .  How do I do this? I need help. Thanks in advance

```
public class salomon {

        public static void main(String[] args) {
          Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
            int n = in.nextInt();
            int[] a = new int[n];
            int[] minHeap = new int[n];
            int[] maxHeap = new int[n];
            int minHeapSize = 0;
            int maxHeapSize = 0;

            float currentMedian = 0;

            for (int a_i = 0; a_i < n; a_i++) {
                a[a_i] = in.nextInt();
                if (a[a_i] < currentMedian) {
                    maxHeap[maxHeapSize++] = a[a_i];
                    // making sure the max heap has maximum value at the top
                    if (maxHeap[maxHeapSize - 1] > maxHeap[0]) {
                        swap(maxHeap, maxHeapSize - 1, 0);
                    }
                } else {
                    minHeap[minHeapSize++] = a[a_i];
                    // making sure the min heap has minimum value at the top
                    if (minHeap[minHeapSize - 1] < minHeap[0]) {
                        swap(minHeap, minHeapSize - 1, 0);
                    }
                }

                // if the difference is more than one
                if (Math.abs(maxHeapSize - minHeapSize) > 1) {
                    if (maxHeapSize > minHeapSize) {
                        swap(maxHeap, maxHeapSize - 1, 0);
                        minHeap[minHeapSize++] = maxHeap[--maxHeapSize];
                        swap(minHeap, 0, minHeapSize - 1);
                        buildMaxHeap(maxHeap, maxHeapSize);
                    } else {
                        swap(minHeap, minHeapSize - 1, 0);
                        maxHeap[maxHeapSize++] = minHeap[--minHeapSize];
                        swap(maxHeap, 0, maxHeapSize - 1);
                        buildMinHeap(minHeap, minHeapSize);
                    }
                }

                // calculate the median
                if (maxHeapSize == minHeapSize) {
                    currentMedian = (minHeap[0] + maxHeap[0]);
                    currentMedian = currentMedian / 2;
                } else if (maxHeapSize > minHeapSize) {
                    currentMedian = maxHeap[0];
                } else {
                    currentMedian = minHeap[0];
                }

                System.out.println(currentMedian);

            }

        }

        static void buildMaxHeap(int[] input, int heapSize) {
            int depth = (heapSize - 1) / 2;
            for (int i = depth; i >= 0; i--) {
                maxHeapify(input, i, heapSize);
            }
        }

        static void maxHeapify(int[] input, int i, int heapSize) {
            int left = 2 * i + 1;
            int right = 2 * i + 2;

            // find the largest
            int largest = i;

            if (left < heapSize && input[left] > input[largest]) {
                largest = left;
            }

            if (right < heapSize && input[right] > input[largest]) {
                largest = right;
            }

            if (largest != i) {
                //swap
                swap(input, i, largest);
                //recursive call
                maxHeapify(input, largest, heapSize);
            }
        }

        static void buildMinHeap(int[] input, int heapSize) {
            int depth = (heapSize - 1) / 2;
            for (int i = depth; i >= 0; i--) {
                minHeapify(input, i, heapSize);
            }
        }

        static void minHeapify(int[] input, int i, int heapSize) {
            int left = 2 * i + 1;
            int right = 2 * i + 2;

            // find the smallest
            int smallest = i;

            if (left < heapSize && input[left] < input[smallest]) {
                smallest = left;
            }

            if (right < heapSize && input[right] < input[smallest]) {
                smallest = right;
            }

            if (smallest != i) {
                //swap
                swap(input, i, smallest);
                //recursive call
                minHeapify(input, smallest, heapSize);
            }
        }

        static void swap(int[] input, int i, int j) {
            if (i == j)
                return;
            int temp = input[i];
            input[i] = input[j];
            input[j] = temp;
        }
    }
```

When I typed 6, 12, 4, 5, 3, 8, 7  and enter - I get the Moving median

```
12.0
8.0
5.0
4.5
5.0
6.0
```

I want to replace the scanner with an array {6, 12, 4, 5, 3, 8, 7}`
instead and how do I adjust the code.  Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first value `6` is the array length. Assuming you intend for that to remain, you would remove everything that "isn't an elephant" (namely all of the median calculations), and rename `int[] a` to `int[] f`. Like,

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    int n = in.nextInt();
    int[] f = new int[n];
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        f[i] = in.nextInt();
    }
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(f));
}
```

When executed with your example input, this outputs

```
[12, 4, 5, 3, 8, 7]
```

If you **really** did want the six as well, then you would need to add it. Like,

```
int[] f = new int[n + 1];
f[0] = n;
for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
    f[i] = in.nextInt();
}
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(f));
```

which outputs (as requested)

```
[6, 12, 4, 5, 3, 8, 7]
```

Comment: What I intend to do is remove the scanner and instead of typing the values I replace it with { 6, 12, 4, 5, 3, 8, 7 }.  I think you are repeating my question @ Elliott

Comment: @Jonatino `int[] f = { 6, 12, 4, 5, 3, 8, 7 }; `- if that ***still*** isn't what you want, then you need to start giving us some examples.

Comment: Thanks Elliot for your response. What I want to do is replace the int n  with the array or number list  6 12  4  5  3  8  7  instead of typing it using scanner @Elliot

Comment: `int n` is one value. That is seven values. **Clarify** what you mean.

Comment: Hello Elliot thanks for your response. What I am trying to do is  instead of typing the numbers using scanner in the computer. I want to use an array instead. How do I adjust the code. I have also refined  my question. Thanks for your patience @Elliot

Comment: As I have already mentioned: `int[] f = { 6, 12, 4, 5, 3, 8, 7 };` that is a single line which defines and initializes an array without using scanner.